# Why does dynamically adding a list item work in Chrome and Firefox but not in IE8?

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

I have some jQuery code which works great in Firefox and Chrome, but does not work in Internet Explorer 8 (haven't tested in other IE versions). Internet Explorer is running in standards mode.

The intent of the code below is to create a new list item on the fly. Its content is set to that of a form that is inside of a hidden section element. What happens when using IE is that the section element becomes unhidden and the li is added to the list, but is empty.

What's wrong with this code in IE?

```
$('ul.elementlist').on('click', '.add-element-icon', function (event) {
    var plusIcon = $(this);
    plusIcon.hide();

    var parentLi = plusIcon.parent();

    var before = parentLi.attr('id');

    var after = parentLi.next().attr('id');
    if (typeof after === "undefined") {
        after = 'none';
    }

    var li = $('<li class="element">').html($('section.add-element').html());
    $('input[name="elementBefore"]', li).val(before);
    $('input[name="elementAfter"]', li).val(after);
    li.insertAfter(parentLi);
});
```

Comment: Is it running in IE8 standards mode or IE7 standards mode?

Comment: @Kroehre It is IE8 standards mode.

Comment: Try adding this before any of your code, just to confirm it isn't the problem. `document.createElement("section");`

Comment: try closing the li in your creation string, $('<li class="element"></li>')

Comment: @Kevin B - I tried adding document.createElement("section") to the top of the JQuery code, and it didn't change anything - still works fine in Chrome, and Firefox, but still same behavior in IE8.  Also, the section.add-element does already exist, but it's hidden by our CSS.

Comment: @Rob - I hadn't noticed that our li tag wasn't terminated, I've added the terminating tag, and still get the same behavior - works in Chrome and Firefox just fine, but not in IE8.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using the `section` element I would guess that you are making use of other HTML5 elements and are using an HTML5 doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html>`. Under these assumptions I would assert you need to do a few things to make your markup "IE friendly."

First ensure that IE truly is running in [IE8 Standards compatibility mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288325%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#DCModes)<sup>*</sup> by adding the following meta tag to your head section:

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=8"/>
```

Immediately following the standards compatibility setting add a reference to [html5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) which is a JavaScript shiv for IE to recognize and style HTML5 elements:

```
<!--[if IE]>
    <script src="http://html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Between these two changes you should be good to go. After the changes force IE to do a full resource refresh by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.

<sub>* If this is a new web site you may want to consider using `IE=edge` as it tells Internet Explorer to use the highest mode available.</sub>

Comment: @Fresheyeball I wasn't aware of `IE=edge`. ***blush***